# How to arrange my xml file into datatable then bind to the gridview

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am making web application. I got the httpresponse  into xml file so I want first this xml file arrange in datatable then bind into the grid view.

this is my code :-

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{

     StreamReader responsereader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

     var responsedata = responsereader.ReadToEnd();
     xmldoc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(responsedata);
     xmldoc.Save(@"C:\New folder\myfile.xml");

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         DataRow dr;
         dt.Columns.Add("hotelId");
         dt.Columns.Add("name");
         dt.Columns.Add("address1");
         dt.Columns.Add("address2");
         dt.Columns.Add("city");
         dt.Columns.Add("postalCode");
         dt.Columns.Add("countryCode");
         dr = dt.NewRow();

         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HotelListResponse));
         HotelListResponse hx = new HotelListResponse();
         hx.Items = new hoteltype[7];

       Stream reader = new FileStream(@"C:\New folder\myfile.xml", FileMode.Open);

       HotelListResponse hlist = (HotelListResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

           dt.ReadXml(@"C:\New folder\myfile.xml");
           //foreach(hoteltype ht in hlist.htype){
           this.GridView1.Visible = true;
           GridView1.DataSource = dt;
           GridView1.DataBind();
           //} 

          //responsereader.Close();
           //request.GetResponse().Close();

       }
   }
     catch (WebException ex)
     {
         if (ex.Response == null)
             throw new NullReferenceException("WebException response");
         throw ex;
     }

}
```

Here HotelListResponse my class file.actually In program I am using custom attribute. I am posting pastbin link also it's contain my whole code.

http://pastebin.com/C2q4JYYt

Comment: Something is not quite right in the code above. Too many closed braces. Could you fix it removing the unneeded one?

Comment: Do you get JSON response ? If so, why convert it to XML and fill Datatable, deserialize JSON to list of objects and bind that to GridView

Comment: my project need xml so that's why I convert. If Possible can you see my pastebin link and give me solution , I need. here I am totally confused.

Comment: Hey Steve sorry, I didn't post my whole code. If Possible can you see my pastebin link .